# Is there a way to tell flexbox to wrap columns after a certain number of elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve a view that will have items 1-5 in a single column and items 6-10 in the next column. Is there an easy way to achieve this using flex WITHOUT setting an explicit height on the flex container or using JQuery? I have a fiddle with the non-working version on top, and what I'm going for on the bottom (but this is using an explicit height).

https://jsfiddle.net/h6s9ds5a/

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div>Item 8</div>
  <div>Item 9</div>
  <div>Item 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *WITHOUT setting an explicit height on the flex container* ... Then how are the flex items supposed to know where to wrap? You've enabled `wrap`. But without a limit on the container, there's nothing telling the line of flex items to break.

Comment: Right. I was hoping there was some way to tell the flex container to cap at 5 child elements. I didn't see anything in the documentation, but I was hoping someone knew a hack :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, by using two wrappers, but that might not work for you: https://jsfiddle.net/h6s9ds5a/2/

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper .column {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.column div {
  flex-direction: column;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>Item 6</div>
    <div>Item 7</div>
    <div>Item 8</div>
    <div>Item 9</div>
    <div>Item 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is wrapper for both the columns

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col1">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div>Item 6</div>
    <div>Item 7</div>
    <div>Item 8</div>
    <div>Item 9</div>
    <div>Item 10</div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: Both of these are pretty close, the only downside is that if Item 6's height > Item 1's, this will break the layout. I'm not sure there's an easy way to do this besides having an ugly DOM with Item 1, then Item 6, then Item 2, then Item 7, etc...